# Get selected value of a number model spinner

Tags: java, integer, spinner

How do you get the selected value from a number based spinner in java?

As i side note why does android always come up under the search term spinner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JSpinner` has a `SpinnerModel`, that stores the selected Value, Bounds of the Values and step sizes, etc.

```
JSpinner spinner;
Object value = spinner.getModel().getValue();
```

Also other Spinners work this way. It is based on the Model-View-Controller(MVC)-Pattern and seperates the Data from their presentation and manipulation.